# c "swprintf_s" access violation

Tags: c, string, access-violation

I am trying to generate some file names automatically. The following was working:

```
unsigned int fileCounter()
{
    static unsigned int fileNo = 0;
    return fileNo++;
}

void createFile(WCHAR* sourceName)  
{
    static const WCHAR wSpec[] = L"c:/test/%s%3u.bmp";
    WCHAR wFileName[MAX_PATH];
    swprintf_s(wFileName, MAX_PATH, wSpec, sourceName, fileCounter());
}

// called by
createFile(TEXT("somename"));
```

I tried to separate the above function into a separate dll project (where the `createFile` function is exported, using the typical

```
#ifdef MY_EXPORTS
#define MY_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MY_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

MY_API void createFile(WCHAR* sourceName);
```

in the header file included in the source caller, and I get an access violation error on the `swprintf_s`

I have tried to replace with the "unsafe" version, but I get the same error. (same if I used the sprintf_s and CHAR* variables)

Also have tried (suggested in a similar question)

```
swprintf_s(wFileName, _countof(wFileName), wSpec, sourceName, fileCounter());
```

I still get

```
(5ec.4d4): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
```

I can't figure out  what is wrong...

Comment: So, the wheels fell off when you moves this code to a DLL, is that correct ?

Comment: yes - was working before i did that...

Comment: Are they both using the same VC runtime (debug mt dll, for example) and using the same *calling convention* ? (_cdecl vs _stdcall, etc). ?

Comment: yes they are, other functions called in the same dll work fine, only difference I can tell from the two projects is that he caller defines UNICODE and _UNICODE and the dependent dll doesn't (though I tried to define them and didn't change result)

Comment: One odd thing I noticed was that trying to debug print TEXT("Source name: %s\n"), sourceName only gave me the first letter... I expected the word

Comment: Is your library built with UNICODE option?

Comment: That's because the DLL is not using Unicode. `OutputDebugString` will default to `OutputDebugStringA` and that `TEXT` macro wrapper will become a no-op. (no `L"` preamble). Thus you're sending a `WCHAR*` to a function expecting `CHAR*`. Frankly I'm surprised you didn't get a big fat compiler warning.

Comment: Change string to be L"c:/test/%ls%3u.bmp"

Comment: This thing should be debuggable. And if you installed VC with all the whistles it should include the VC runtime library so you can trace into the CRT functions. This is odd.

Comment: This is code i put in a driver - only way to debug is attach windbg to a process...

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Thank you that didn't work

Comment: Adding UNICODE and _UNICODE allowed me to debug print the source name - still same error on the swprintf_s

Comment: Humor me. Try `LPWSTR pwsz = wFileName; swprintf_s(pwsz, _countof(wFileName), wSpec, sourceName, fileCounter());`

Comment: @WhozCraig Same problem

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you besides wire up symbols and a debugger. You're calling it correctly. Either the calling convention is mismatched (which I mentioned earlier) or the wrong function is being called. The previous comment was to ensure the template<> version was *not* being incorrectly pieced in. I'd also check and make sure both lib and exe are using the same settings for `wchar_t` as a native type or not (honestly makes no difference which as long as they match).

Comment: How do I do that ? (check and make sure both lib and exe are using the same settings for wchar_t as a native type) - where do I find that info or how can i print it out ?

Comment: Its part of the C++ compiler settings. But I'd still make sure they're both using the *same calling convention* (caller and callee). Btw, pretty gutsy calling CRT code from a sys driver. I avoid that like the plague =P

Comment: Because I don't know any better... I define it out in release mode ... what would be the alternative ?

Comment: This function doesn't actually do anything after `swprintf_s` so it is redundant... I guess the "real code" has more code after `swprintf_s`, is the error happening with only the code you have posted present?